# « Ça ne marche pas » qu'est-ce que ça signifie ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

On utilise *marcher* pour quelque chose comme faire une promenade, n'est-ce pas ?

Je pense que cette phrase a pour signification « it does not work », est-ce que c'est le cas ?

Comment: Il suffit de vérifier dans un [dictionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/marcher)…

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Je ne cherche pas pour seulement un mot, je ne comprend pas la signification de cette phrase qui est « Ça ne marche pas » et je voudrai être sur.

Comment: Justement un dictionnaire est fait pour ça, il te donne la **traduction**. Clique sur le lien que donne StéphaneGimenez ou un [autre dictionnaire](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/marcher), mais ça se trouve très facilement.

Comment: Je trouve que les -1 à la question sont un peu abusifs ici : des fois, pour comprendre quelque chose, on est complètement paumé, et un coup de main, même sur un truc complètement stupide et évident, permet de se sortir d'affaire. Et de plus il n'est pas évident, dans toutes les cultures, que "marcher" puisse avoir évidemment avoir le sens de "fonctionner", même si c'est écrit dans les dictionnaires.

Comment: Autant je suis en l'occurence d'accord avec Istao et ne moissoye pas, autant je soutiens d'abord et avant tout les opinions particulières de chacun, et [leurs raisons quelquonques pour moinsoir](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/24105/197593). (Non, je n'ai pas de choix définitif sur les mots.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aux deux questions la réponse est **oui**.

L'expression est très habituelle.

Elle parait fautive du point de vue du sens de marcher, lorsqu'il s'attache à une personne. Quelques fois on dit *Ça ne fonctionne pas* à la place, mais c'est ignorer que *marcher* a aussi le sens de *fonctionner*.